# Is having a long running boto SNSConnection a bad idea?

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications, celery, boto, amazon-sns

I'm using `boto` and SNS to send push notifications to iOS. I've made a wrapper class, `APNS`, that keeps a long running `boto.SNSConnection` as a member variable.

I'd like to have an instance of the `APNS` class as a global variable, so I can use `celery` to send push notifications in the background.

Are there any problems with keeping a long running `SNSConnection` and re-using it, or should I be creating a new connection every time I want to publish a message?

Comment: I haven't worked with SNS but I use long running connections for SQS and S3 for days and haven't had any issue, you might want a process monitor to check if process is down and rerun it, that way my processes run for months at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You should be reusing the SNS connection for best performance. That said, please ensure that you detect and re-establish the connection if it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the signature of the SNSConnection, There is no timeout parameter so my guess there is no problem using a long term connection.

```
class SNSConnection(AWSQueryConnection):
    """
    Amazon Simple Notification Service
    """


      def __init__(self, aws_access_key_id=None, aws_secret_access_key=None,
                 is_secure=True, port=None, proxy=None, proxy_port=None,
                 proxy_user=None, proxy_pass=None, debug=0,
                 https_connection_factory=None, region=None, path='/',
                 security_token=None, validate_certs=True,
                 profile_name=None):
```